# Find the IP address of a newly-booted Raspberry Pi

Tags: mac-address, arp, ip-address

I've attached a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu to my home network with a cable. It is booted up and connected to the network. The Pi has no keyboard, mouse, or monitor. If I know the IP address that was assigned to the robot, they could ssh into it.

It turns out that RasPis have a known OUI {Organizationally Unique Identifier} to their MAC addresses. All of their MAC addresses start with `b8:27:eb`. So if I could get a list of all the MAC addresses on my network I would be golden.

But...

```
arp -a | grep "b8:27:eb"
```

Should should do it. Except that apr -a does not produce an exhaustive and up to date list. Any ideas on how I could get an up to date list of MAC addresses on computers on the network, or get the IP address of a newly attached Raspberry Pi?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it not have ports where you can connect a keyboard, mouse, and monitor?

Comment: The board has them but the users for whom I am writing the instructions will not have those.

Comment: You can know the MAC address of a pi before it starts if you assign it one when you prepare the micro-SD card. You add `smsc95xx.macaddr=hh:hh:hh:hh:hh:hh` to the end of the /boot/cmdline.txt file. I find this useful to quickly tell my Pis apart.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve that is from the device that controls your home network, i.e., your home router. It indeed has a list of MAC and IP addresses of the devices in the network. Regardless, if you'd know the complete MAC you usually can simply derive the IPv6 from it as IPv6 doesn't use DHCP (by default).

Comment: Not an answer: but this just appeared in my blog roll: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/what-the-blink-is-my-ip-address/

Answer (score 23):

Assuming not too large a network range you can force the ARP table to be populated before you look through it. These examples are for a typical home network on 192.168.1.0-255

```
nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24          # Ping scan
arp -na | grep 'at b8:27:eb:'    # Match the RPi devices
```

Otherwise, you could look for devices with an open SSH port,

```
nmap -oG - -p 22 192.168.1.0/24  | grep /open/
```

Or look at your router's DHCP assignment table to see what addresses it has recently allocated.

Comment: In my home network the second command worked and took only about 30 seconds. It produced two IP addresses, one of which was correct. I have to quickly go find out which is the other one :)

Comment: This is the approach I used the last time when I needed to find out the address of the IPMI interface of a newly plugged-in server.

Comment: This answer understands that the ARP table only gets filled with things you've attempted to communicate with. The `nmap` tries to contact every IP address, which fills the ARP table - a nice solution. That said, personally, I look in my router's DHCP tables to find my Pis

Comment: @RalphBolton yes, I would, too.

Answer (score 8):

This is an indirect but sufficient answer. I realized that if I know the hostname for the Raspberry Pi then I can use ssh pi@myrobot.local. That worked.

Comment: If there is a DNS record then why not just find the address with `nslookup` or `dig`?

Comment: @NasirRiley There probably is no DNS record, the host itself responds to a mDNS query, as evidenced by the `.local` name.

Comment: @JohanMyréen No matter. If he can SSH into the machine then he can get the address that way.

Comment: I use the same to ssh to my pi.However I am wondering what happens when there are 2 rpi in the same network with the same hostname.

Comment: @NasirRiley `local` is the domain name used for Zeroconf, which is a domain name system without central resolver. Most modern Linux distributions come with it preinstalled, just as Raspberry Pi OS does.

Comment: You al seem to know about .local. I have found it to be "unreliable". I put quotes because all I can tell is that sometimes it doesn't seem to work. Not necessarily in a cli but maybe when used (via an env variable) in code. With that vague impression, can anyone estimate what might be happening?

Comment: @rexkogitans I understand that. Like I said, if it can be resolved, no matter the method, he can get the IP address just by SSHing into the machine. That's enough to do what he wants. He can go ahead and accept his own answer.

Comment: @ManosKounelakis Two hosts with the same name in the same network make a lot of trouble. If this were the case, you had to rename one of them.

Comment: For this to work, your local router needs to support mDNS - glad it worked for you, but it won't work for everyone. Even those with a suitable router may have set their DNS servers to some common Internet services, thus by-passing the router. Even though the router knows the Pi, and has a name assigned for it, lookups have to go there to find this information.

Comment: @RalphBolton no, zeroconf doesn't work like that - there's no requirement for a central manager such as the router. Each host broadcasts its name and services periodically, and each other host collects that information ready for users' enquiries

Comment: But @roaima I have noticed that .local is not always reliable... Don't know why that is...

Comment: @RalphBolton No, any router should support this.  The only networking requirement for mDNS is for [local subnetwork multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#IPv4).  Since this is implemented by the ethernet switch (not the router) you're unlikely to find a router that doesn't support it (See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#ethernet)

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I am the author of this tool.

Try this tool, written for this exact purpose.  It currently runs on Windows.  It listens to traffic on the network and lists hosts that come up, such as your raspberry pi.  It performs lookup in the IEEE OUI to detect the manufacturer.

https://github.com/jwalthour/passiveAggressor

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized you were asking how to do this from an Ubuntu machine.  This answer will not be helpful.

Comment: Well I also have a Mac. But no windows. Looks great though!

Comment: Well, if we are at it, does it at least run on Linux/Mac through Wine? ;)

Comment: @Ruslan, that's an interesting question.  It relies on WinPcap, so I'm not optimistic, but it seems like that'd be worth testing.

Answer (score 3):

You can know the MAC address of a pi before it starts if you assign it one when you prepare the micro-SD card. You add

```
smsc95xx.macaddr=hh:hh:hh:hh:hh:hh
```

(hh are hex bytes) to the end of the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file. I find this useful to quickly tell my Pis apart. Doing this overrides the default behaviour at boot time.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official documentation [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ip-address.md)

You could try pinging `raspberrypi.local` or just `raspberrypi` from a computer connected in the same network and grab the IP address from the ping response.

```
ping raspberrypi.local
```

or if you want ipv4 address

```
ping -4 raspberrypi.local
```

Comment: I'd suggest that a useful enhancement would be for the RPi to do a broadcast ping when it starts up, limited to say ten counts. That would make sure that as many systems as possible had a reference to it in their ARP cache, which could be consulted by users who didn't have privileged access to the DHCP server.

Comment: Actually I have been having confusion on the difference between ARP and DHCP. Can you point me to some resources from where I can learn?

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Imagine if you had 1000 PIs and they all booted at once?

Comment: @Neil So? That's a few thousand ICMP and ARP messages on a LAN, which is minimal overhead compared with the DHCP handshaking.

Comment: @Dhushyanth Wikipaedia is always a good starting point, but in 500 chars ARP is a low-level protocol by which host A can ask the other local hosts which one will respond to host B's IP address (it uses a MAC broadcast). DHCP is a somewhat higher-level protocol by which host A says "I don't have an IP address yet, can the local DHCP server please give me one" (it uses UDP on top of IP). Every host supporting IP implicitly responds to ARP requests, DHCP requests are normally broadcast and are responded to by a dedicated DHCP server which in domestic kit will usually be in an ADSL router etc. HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool called `arp-scan`. It performs the scan by sending ARP requests for the scanned IPs. To scan your subnet run:

```
arp-scan -lI eth0
```

while of course substituting your interface. It *may* require superuser privileges to run. The tool also uses an OUI database to show you the OUI associated with the MAC addresses which responded, quite often it also detects duplicate IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *all* Pi's have MAC addresses start that start with `b8:27:eb` is a bit erroneous.  My (limited) home network has Pi MAC prefix's of not only `b8:27:eb:...` but also `dc:a6:32:...` and `7e:9e:a0:...` (A Pi4 and Pi3b(+?)).

In any event, I use either `nmap` or `arp-scan` to find new system IP's.  I also have an `/etc/crontab @reboot sleep 60` script that just does an `ifconfig`.

This

1. gives me the current IP(s) and
2. alerts me if a reboot has occurred.

This assumes that the resulting cronjob email is delivered to you.